# Класс для использования в list

Tags: c++, классы, list

Есть два класса:

```
class ChangeButton
{
public:
    ChangeButton(string ButtonCode, int ButtonType)
    {
        btn_code = ButtonCode;
        btn_type = ButtonType;
    }

    std::string get_btn_code()
    {
        return btn_code;
    }

    int get_btn_type()
    {
        return btn_type;
    }

private:
    std::string btn_code;
    int btn_type;
};

class Change
{
public:
    Change(list<ChangeButton> Change_Button, list<ChangeButton> Change_To_Button)
    {
        change_btn_list = Change_Button;
        change_to_btn_list = Change_To_Button;
    }

    list<ChangeButton> get_list_change_btn()
    {
        return change_btn_list;
    }

    list<ChangeButton> get_list_change_to_btn()
    {
        return change_to_btn_list;
    }

private:
    list<ChangeButton> change_btn_list;
    list<ChangeButton> change_to_btn_list;
};
```

В коде мне необходимы:

```
list<Change> Changes;
list<ChangeButton> ChangeButtons;
list<ChangeButton> ChangeToButtons;
```

При компиляции проекта выскакивают многочисленные ошибки типа: Change необъявленный идентификатор, символ не является ни классом шаблон, ни функцией шаблон и т.п.

Я новичок в С++, поэтому делаю похоже как в С#.

В чём моя ошибка, подскажите пожалуйста. Буду благодарен, если покажете на примере.

---

```
// JsonReader.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/writer.h"
#include "rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"
#include "rapidjson/istreamwrapper.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream> 
#include <list>

using namespace rapidjson;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        list<Change> Changes;
    list<ChangeButton> ChangeButtons;
    list<ChangeButton> ChangeToButtons;

    ifstream ifs("json.js");
    IStreamWrapper isw(ifs);
    Document documentFromFile;
    documentFromFile.ParseStream(isw);

    Value& arr = documentFromFile["changes"]; // open the "changes" tag
    if (arr.IsArray())
    {
        for (SizeType i = 0; i < arr.Size(); i++) // foreach the "changes" tag
        {
            Value& changes = arr[i];
            Value& change_btns = changes["change_btns"];
            if (change_btns.IsArray())
            {
                for (SizeType i = 0; i < change_btns.Size(); i++) // 
                {
                    Value& btn = arr[i];
                    cout << btn.GetType() << '\n';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

class ChangeButton
{
public:
    ChangeButton(string ButtonCode, int ButtonType)
    {
        btn_code = ButtonCode;
        btn_type = ButtonType;
    }

    std::string get_btn_code()
    {
        return btn_code;
    }

    int get_btn_type()
    {
        return btn_type;
    }

private:
    std::string btn_code;
    int btn_type;
};

class Change
{
public:
    Change(list<ChangeButton> Change_Button, list<ChangeButton> Change_To_Button)
    {
        change_btn_list = Change_Button;
        change_to_btn_list = Change_To_Button;
    }

    list<ChangeButton> get_list_change_btn()
    {
        return change_btn_list;
    }

    list<ChangeButton> get_list_change_to_btn()
    {
        return change_to_btn_list;
    }

private:
    list<ChangeButton> change_btn_list;
    list<ChangeButton> change_to_btn_list;
};
```

Comment: заголовки включили? пространство имен?

Comment: Эмм. Не могу ответить, но классы находится в исполняемом же файле.

Comment: `#include <list>`, `#include <string>`, `using std::list`, `using std::string`

Comment: #include <list>, #include <string>, using namespace std, но ошибки всё равно сохраняются

Comment: в проекте один файл? если нет, добавьте информацию о том, как включаются другие файлы, где определена функция `main`

Comment: Это стандартное консольное приложение.

Comment: файл, в котором объявлены `Change` и `ChangeButton` подключен?

Comment: Так они же объявлены в этом же файле (JsonReader.cpp). Зачем этот же файл в этом же файле ещё раз объявлять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Классы нужно объявлять до момента использования. Функции и функции-члены можно объявлять предварительно, например так:

```
class Foo{
   int v;
public:
   Foo(int);
}

int main(){
 //....
}
Foo::Foo(int v){
    //...
}
```

Еще лучше вынести объявления в заголовочный файл.

Edit: Сами классы предварительно объявлять тоже можно, но при этом доступны только ссылки и указатели на них и запрещено их разыменование.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!

Comment: "Предварительно" в данном случае не получится.